# What is the difference between .js and .min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript graphic libraries for my project. In all libraries I am finding the files like

```
abc.js - abc.min.js
xyz.js - xyz.min.js
```

What does **.min** indicate? Is it some sort of syntax of making javascript libraries?

Comment: **Min**-ified. -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Please do some research before posting the question immediately !

Answer (score 40):

`.min` is the minified version, and it is primarily used while the website is being launched in order to reduce the load for the particular website.

Basically all the long variable names and function names are converted into shorter ones during the process of minifying. As consequence it would reduce the size of that particular file, so it would less the loading speed of the website.

On the other hand normal `.js` is the one which is used until the site being launched, meaning while the site in the mode of development/testing.

Comment: I think it is more to save network bandwith rather than the load.

Comment: @OskarsPakers: Well, the faster the file comes across the network, the faster the website loads (modulo various ways of improving perceived load time).

Comment: @OskarsPakers is right. Normally the size of a js file is relatively small compared to the users' bandwidth, therefore, a less size of the js files doesn't help a lot in most cases while on the server-side, the bandwidth is precious.